# Почему я не могу прижать черный блок к правому краю?

Tags: css

У меня есть бургер меню, которое открывает окно(черный блок) с пунктами меню. Но есть проблема: я не могу его прижать к правому углу экрана. В чем может быть проблема?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

HTML:

```css
.header{

  height: 100px;
  background: #2c2e47;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;


}
.logo{
  font-size: 40px;
  animation: logo-loop 10s infinite;
  margin-left: 20px;

}
@keyframes logo-loop{
  50%{
    color: red;
  }
  75%{
    color: blue;
  }
  100%{
    color: #872BB6FF;
  }
}
.burger-btn{
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;

  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: 20px ;
  justify-content:end;
}
.burger-btn span{
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  top:13px;
  width: 30px;
  background: cornflowerblue;
  height: 2px;
}
.burger-btn:before{
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  width: 30px;
  background: cornflowerblue;
  height: 2px;
}
.burger-btn:after{
  content:'';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 30px;
  background: cornflowerblue;
  height: 2px;
}
.menu{
  position: fixed;
  width: 100vw;
  height:100vh;
  top:100px;
  right: 0;
}
.blur{
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  right: 30%;
  background: #1b6ec2;
  position: absolute;
}
.menu-content{
  width: 30%;
  height: 100%;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">

  <div class="logo">
    <b>gg</b>
  </div>
  <div (click)="opens()"   class = "burger-btn">
    <span></span>
  </div>

</div>
<div class = "menu" *ngIf="open" (click)="opens()">

  <div class="menu-content" (click)="$event.stopPropagation()">
    <div class="menu-header"></div>
      <ul>

        <li>
          <a></a>
        </li>

      </ul>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

у вас `.menu` и так размером с ширину экрана, поэтому никуда вы ее не запозиционируете

а для `.menu-content` никакого позиционирования не стояло

так что вы или одно исправьте или другое (в примере я второе подправил)

```css
.header{

  height: 100px;
  background: #2c2e47;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;


}
.logo{
  font-size: 40px;
  animation: logo-loop 10s infinite;
  margin-left: 20px;

}
@keyframes logo-loop{
  50%{
    color: red;
  }
  75%{
    color: blue;
  }
  100%{
    color: #872BB6FF;
  }
}
.burger-btn{
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;

  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: 20px ;
  justify-content:end;
}
.burger-btn span{
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  top:13px;
  width: 30px;
  background: cornflowerblue;
  height: 2px;
}
.burger-btn:before{
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  width: 30px;
  background: cornflowerblue;
  height: 2px;
}
.burger-btn:after{
  content:'';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 30px;
  background: cornflowerblue;
  height: 2px;
}
.menu{
  position: fixed;
  width: 100vw;
  height:100vh;
  top:100px;
  right: 0;
}
.blur{
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  right: 30%;
  background: #1b6ec2;
  position: absolute;
}
.menu-content{
position: absolute;
right: 0px;
  width: 30%;
  height: 100%;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">

  <div class="logo">
    <b>gg</b>
  </div>
  <div (click)="opens()"   class = "burger-btn">
    <span></span>
  </div>

</div>

<div class = "menu" *ngIf="open" (click)="opens()">

  <div class="menu-content" (click)="$event.stopPropagation()">
    <div class="menu-header"></div>
      <ul>

        <li>
          <a></a>
        </li>

      </ul>
  </div>

</div>
```